# where does the primary stress fall in "save on fares"?

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

In the phrase "save on fares," does the primary stress fall on "save" or "on"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: The stress wouldn't normally be on "ON". You can stress either of the other words depending on what you are trying to say.

Comment: It depends on the context. Most people would, however, put the primary stress on 'fares' and secondary stress on 'save'.